# How to update entity related with ApplicationUser using EF6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns

I have problem with updating entity related with application user in ASP.NET MVC. I have one-to-many relationship between `ApplicationUser` and `Order`. This is my entities and relation config:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<Order> HandlingOrders { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //some properties

    public string OperatorId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("OperatorId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser Operator { get; set; }
}

protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().HasMany(n => n.HandlingOrders)
                                          .WithOptional(n => n.Operator)
                                          .HasForeignKey(n => n.OperatorId);
}
```

The problem is, when I try to save `Order` in my controller, it fails with `InvalidOperationException` and message

> The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects.

It happens because on one hand I use "Unit of Work" and "Generic Repository" to save `Order`. From other hand I use `ApplicationUserManager` to save `ApplicationUser`.

```
public class OperatorController : Controller
{
    private readonly UnitOfWork _unitOfWork;

    private ApplicationUserManager _userManager
    {
        get { return HttpContext.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>(); }
    }
}
```

As a result I get two contexts: first is `IOwinContext` from `GetOwinContext()`, second is my regular `ApplicationContext`, created (or is creating?) in "Unit of Work". And this contexts cause exception.

Could anyone suggest me, what is best in this situation? I fought about writing repository for `ApplicationUser`, but I have never seen such practice in articles, so I am not sure.

Comment: Start with the obvious. Is ApplicationUser in one context (like the default IdentityDbContext) and is Order declared in another like ApplicationContext? That would cause your error. If so, just have your ApplicationContext inherit from IdentityDbContext.

Comment: @SteveGreene No, my `ApplicationContext` is already inherited from `IdentityDbContext<TUser>`. Actually, I have two instances of one context is created by two different ways, and that cause error. Problem is I don't know how to work with users without `ApplicationUserManager`, which, as far as I can see, cann't be initialized with `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: If you are just referencing users, you don't need a UserManager. For example, `ApplicationUser myUser = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id  == myUserId);` will grab an identity user. If you are going to change passwords, etc you need the UserManager. Show the relevant repository code.

Comment: @SteveGreene It should be something like [that](https://gist.github.com/QuarK264/7fa24f4a4175d948f9aabf1e02ac7a61), I think (stubs in last three method is, because class must implement interface). This should work, until I don't have to change something in user:)

Answer (score 1):

**First way Explained:**
According to your error message, as far as I know, it is maybe when you change the structure of context, but can update database, so I suggest you need update database before save .

You can use the database migration commands to update the database without altering the data that you have as follows:
Go to Tools –> Library Package Manager –> Package Manager Console,
Run the Enable-Migrations command in Package Manager Console,
Add-Migration ,
Update-Database,
Add-Migration (your Project)

**Second way Explained:**
IOwinContext Interface:This wraps OWIN environment dictionary and provides strongly typed accessors.
GetOwinContext Interface with HttpContext:Gets the IOwinContext for the current request.
GetOwinContext Interface with Http Request:Gets the IOwinContext for the current request.
In the case of  ApplicationContext, we can use by this way:

```
Public ApplicationContext:DbContext
{
Public ApplicationContext():base(“ConnectionStringName”)
{
Database.SetInitializer<ApplicationContext>(null);
}
//Dbsets here
}
```

When we attempting to save the different orders in this case, we can use second scenario such as Unit of work through Repository Pattern. It is also flexible way to transfer data from one framework to another too.

Comment: First way: No, I didn't change my entities. Just to be sure, I run "Add-Migration" and it generates empty `Up()` and `Down()`. Second way: I have already used context like this, moreover `DbContext` doesn't fit for apps with individual user authentication. Instead of it `IdentityDbContext<TUser>` must be used.

Comment: If context structure changes the message is: "The model backing the 'ContextName' context has changed since the database was created. Consider using Code First Migrations to update the database"

Comment: This answer makes no sense. The issue is you have 2 contexts for a single update, not that your model is out of sync.